# private variable with closure

Tags: javascript, closures

Hi I was learning how to make private variables with a closure. The reading was fine but when I try to change the variable it is undefined but why ?

```
var myMoney=(function somePrivateElements(){
    var money=23;

    return {
             getMoney: function(){ return money},
             setMoney: function(newMoney){money = newMoney;}
    }
})();

    console.log(myMoney.getMoney()); //23
    console.log(myMoney.setMoney()); //say it is undefined
```

**UPDATE:**

My mistake was here in setMoney 
`setMoney {money = newMoney; return money}`

Comment: Why `this.money`? That's something different than `money`.

Comment: Also, who says what is undefined when and where?

Comment: I removed this.money it also don't work

Comment: Why do you expect `setMoney` to print anything?

Comment: @deceze I don't think you should have outright closed the question. If there's a duplicate go nuts, but it has enough content and an attempt and a solid enough question to bypass the "why isn't this working" (at least, by a mod, if the community decides so, sure). Edit: just my opinion, not strong enough to meta it and make it a big deal!

Comment: @Sterling I admit I may have been a bit trigger happy, but reopening this won't do anyone any good either.

Comment: @deceze agreed, no harm no foul :)

Answer (score 2):

`myMoney.setMoney` doesn't return anything. It accepts a value and then sets it, so the next call to `getMoney` will have the updated value.

Also, you're setting `this.money`, but `this.money` isn't the same as `money`. You would just want `money = newMoney`.

Comment: thx that was the mistake